# Allow blank password fields on User model when updating profile in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

### Edited to include code

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *arg, **kw):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*arg, **kw)

        # re-order so email appears last on this form
        email_field = self.fields.pop('email')
        self.fields['email'] = email_field


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')
```

---

I have a form were users can update their profile details.

Users can optionally update their `passwords` but it's not required in order to update other profile fields.

The problem is my validations are kicking in when the `password` and `password confirmation` fields are blank.

The `User` models `Password` field I believe is a `required=True` and `blank=False` field so I need a way of simply ignoring blank input from forms when validating on this model.

The `User` model is the one that ships with Django:

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Thanks

Comment: Is it a regular form you've written, or a model form ?

Comment: It's a `UserCreationForm`.

Comment: @Ash can you post the code of your form?

Comment: I've added some code above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`UserCreationForm` is intended to be used for **creation**. It's better to create a new ModelForm than using this one.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Feel free to add the password validation field as on UserCreationForm
    password = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Add all the fields you want a user to change
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password') 

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserUpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Or if you want to subclass the `UserCreationForm` which I doesn't recommend. You can do this :

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), required=False
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                            widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserUpdateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        password = self.cleaned_data["password"]
        if password:
            user.set_password(password)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I recommend you to use a simple

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):       
    class Meta:
        model = User
        # Add all the fields you want a user to change
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')
```

For passwords changing there's another dedicated form that your can use which is `django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm` since changing the password is a different process from updating user informations

Comment: I like the last solution. I wasn't aware of the SetPasswordForm form which will be useful elsewhere also.

Comment: This is not working at all, don't know if it's because this is an old answer is from 2012, but the form won't even check if the passwords match before saving

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own password form field and handle it manually. Or you can override clean method and remove password related errors yourself.