# Django: how to unset user password

Tags: python, django, ldap

In our system most users log in using their LDAP credentials (via `django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend` module). Some people, however, have their passwords set directly in Django auth module (they don't have LDAP accounts). Recently, some users had their LDAP accounts created, so they don't need Django passwords anymore. Is there a way to unset those passwords? Django admin panel allows only to change password, not remove it alltogether.

Comment: why do you want to remove the passwords any way? it won't harm you or them

Comment: That's one more thing to maintain, one more thing to exploit (for example LDAP places some requirements on passwords that Djabgo auth backend don't enforce etc).

Answer (score 0):

Extend user model and make password field blank

An example: 
[Allow blank password fields on User model when updating profile in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13932137/allow-blank-password-fields-on-user-model-when-updating-profile-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way. The easiest way that I can think of unregisters the stock user admin, adds a "unset password for selected user" action, and re-registers that new user admin.